# How to use Printershare application in my android application

Tags: android

I want to take a print of pdf file in my application.so,I want to use printershare application which is installed in my mobile.

How to use that printershare application?and how can I send pdf file path through the intent.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setPackage("com.dynamixsoftware.printershare");
i.setDataAndType(data_uri, data_type);
startActivity(i);
```

Where:

`data_uri` - `Uri` of the object to print, such as "file:///sdcard/something.pdf" or "content://something"

`data_type` - MIME type. The following mime types are supported:

`"application/pdf"`
`"text/html"`
`"text/plain"`
`"image/png"`
`"image/jpeg"`
`"application/msword"` - .doc
`"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"` - .docx
`"application/vnd.ms-excel"` - .xls
`"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"` - .xlsx
`"application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"` - .ppt
`"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"` - .pptx